# Missing toolbar for New Message window in Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I no longer have the toolbar at the top of New Message (The one with buttons for Send, Add Attachments..). It is only missing in New Message, if I for example reply to a message, the toolbar is correct.

[image: Missing toolbar]

I can still send the message by selecting Message -> Send in the menu bar.

I have tried going to View -> Customize Toolbar, but it doesn't display any options.

[image: Toolbar customization]

I'm out of ideas. Searching the web I am only able to find the 'Customize Toolbar'-fix. I also haven't minimized the toolbar, as I've seen some solutions suggesting.

Comment: I also have this problem now.

Comment: @sumelic For what it's worth, this issue solved itself for me, I have no idea what was causing it or what I did to put it right. Sorry.

Comment: That happened for me as well, so... I guess it's just a mysterious thing that happened. Glad to hear your problem was solved!

Answer (score 1):

At top of new message page control click and uncheck "Hide Toolbar"